# Best practices to structure a table to hold data per month

Tags: sql, database

When I need to save data for different months in a table. I see two ways to structure tables, either having a column for each month:

```
Year | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May...
```

Or a more slim structure by having only a month and an amount column:

```
Year | Month | Amount
```

Up to this point I have always used the first approach however I'd like to know if there are advantages of using one method over the other, specially regarding data integrity and performance.

Comment: The first is a non-starter. You can see why very simply - try to SUM or AVG data for 12 months.

Comment: There are an infinite number of months in the future.  Tables cannot have an infinite number of columns.

Comment: "infinite number of months"?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Potentially anyway.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I can agree with an "arbitrarily large" number of months, but not an infinite number of them. Our sun will be exiting it's Main Sequence in about another billion years or so ... after that, there will definitely be no months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under most circumstances, the "slimmer" structure is more appropriate for a relational database.  It readily lets you answer questions such as:

- What is the first month with data?
- In how many months is the amount more than $100?
- How often is the amount less than $100?
- What is the percentage improvement from one month to the next?

The pivoted format is quite appropriate for *output* purposes, because people are, well, people and we like to see the monthly data spread out.  However, putting each month on a separate row is more versatile.